# how to start, stop, restart services using gcloud SDK command line

Tags: gcloud

`gcloud app services` provides browse, delete, list, set-traffic commands. Is it possible to stop/start services using the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start/stop individual versions of services, not the whole services:

```
$ gcloud app versions stop --service my-service version1
$ gcloud app versions start --service my-service version1
```

See [An Overview of App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine) for more information on the distinction between services and versions.

Comment: BTW this won't work if you're using an autoscaled service.

Comment: @ingernet, How can I remove / stop an app that is deployed on the autoscaled setting?

Comment: It seems to work for autoscaled services on gae flex